# Magento 2 : Display Ordered Items listing in customer account

Tags: magento2, orders, customer-account, order-items

In Magento 2 customer account I have to add a new tab and when customer visits it then on that page have to display a list of all items from all orders of customers. It will be grids of ordered items.

From that page, the customer will be able to add cart.

I have added tab and page in customer account but not understanding how to get a list of products.

Please suggest me a way.